# Code analysis warnings (IDExxxx) when building a .NET Framework project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

I have enabled several Code Analysis warnings in a .editorconfig file. Visual Studio shows me these warnings. However, when building, no warnings are shown in the build output. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview?tabs=net-7#code-style-analysis=) it says that you can enable the code-style analysis with .NET 5 or later. Is it in any way possible to enable it with a .NET Framework project?

Comment: doesn’t the note literally explain what you are asking? `.NET analyzers are target-framework agnostic. That is, your project does not need to target a specific .NET implementation. The analyzers work for projects that target .NET 5+ as well as earlier .NET versions, such as .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Framework 4.7.2. However, to enable code analysis using the EnableNETAnalyzers property, your project must reference a project SDK. `

Comment: @RandRandom I found a way to enable it without setting EnableNETAnalyzers. EnableNETAnalyzers did nothing for me.

Comment: @HansPassant That did not work. It enabled CAxxxx rules, but not IDExxxx rules. Also it ignored my .editorconfig file and it says that the method is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/33558#issuecomment-780632741), you can add a package reference to `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle` to make it show up in the build output. You don't have to set `EnforceCodeStyleInBuild` in the project file.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people